# Returning an array from a PHP function to jQuery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a PHP function that returns an array. What is the best way to "receive" this using jQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to turn your PHP array into a native JavaScript array, then use jQuery [$.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post), [$.get](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get), or [$.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) methods to fetch this value from your PHP script. I generally use $.post unless I need the special features that $.ajax provides.

Answer (score 3):

I use smarty, and this is how I do it:

```
<?php
$smarty = new Smarty;
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => 'foo');
$smarty->assign('array', $array);
$smarty->display('template.htm');
?>
```

template.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var array = {$array|@json_encode};
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't use smarty you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$array = array('foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => 'foo');
echo 'var array = ' . json_encode($array) . ';'
?>
```

Comment: Yes this is a smarty app im building... that is such a tidy way! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I really like this idea, too bad I get the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error :/

Answer (score 2):

I echo what jkndrkn and Wookai said, but I would add that if you're not using ajax, you can still use json_encode() to insert the array directly into your javascript/jquery code.

Answer (score 1):

Encode it in JSON using [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), print it to the page and then call this page using jQuery (with [$.get()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get) for example).